# Unable to see test attachments added via the API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

My issue was closed prematurely at the Microsoft Developer Community so I'm hoping (and praying) someone from the community may have a suggestion.

Whenever I open a test result in Azure DevOps, it's not loading the full list of attachments linked to the test case. Typically, after a test run as part of a release, I will manually upload some attachments to individual test cases. The attachments are typically a .jpg, and a .mp4. The .mp4 rarely exceeds 10mb.

This is the API test attachments GET request...

```
GET https://[organization]/[project]/_apis/test/Runs/1016852/Results/100000/attachments?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

And here is a screenshot of the results...

[image: results]

Here is an example of an attachment returned by the results...

```
https://[organization]/[project]/_apis/test/Runs/1016852/Results/100000/Attachments/1111488
```

and here is an example running the link in my browser to download the attachment...

[image: attachment download request in the browser]

As you can see, attachment is downloaded and opened succesfully.

Now, when I browse to the test result in Azure DevOps with the following link (Note that the run and result IDs are identical to the above)...

```
https://[organization]/[project]/_testManagement/runs?runId=1016852&_a=resultSummary&resultId=100000%3Ehttps://smartassessor.visualstudio.com/Smart%20End%20Point%20Assessment/_testManagement/runs?runId=1016852&_a=resultSummary&resultId=100000
```

I see only 2 attachments instead of 10...

[image: 2 / 10 attachments]

Here is an example body that I am posting to the attachments endpoint...

```
{
  "stream": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAIAAABvFaqvAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABlSURBVDhP7cxBCsAgDERR739pG/CnGJI0FopQ8O2cjNP6R85QbeNQU7wT1dkijaQ3vkZoWElaoTeJojW01cYh0jwfgiFBV/lEjOZtacijN/nLkOBHhIaVDgn+Wdycp6FXzlCl9wt0Y0cAzHo/zgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
  "fileName": "imageAsFileAttachment.png",
  "comment": "Test attachment upload",
  "attachmentType": "GeneralAttachment"
}
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it according to your description, but unfortunately I could not reproduce your problem. I uploaded the attachments using the rest api. The attachments can be displayed normally in the test case and match the number of attachments queried with the rest api.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can check the set retention time in [Test Retention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7SW9.png) to see if the attachments were automatically deleted. If this is ruled out, there is a recently [event](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/163258954) of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which could affected these services, and it has been resolved. You can check if the issue still exists.

If this issue still exists, here is a case with similar problem. In this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/488459/some-test-steps-attachments-are-lost.html), this problem should be a bug and fixed, but this does not rule out the possibility of recurrence. You can submit a new ticket in the [developer forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) and report the problem as a bug.

Comment: My test retention settings match yours. The problem still persists even though the event of availability degradation has been resolved. The issue has already been raised on developer forum here - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/824439/add-test-results-api-is-returning-200-ok-with-a-li.html but is showing as closed even though I have provided more than enough info. For some reason, when I open a page that should display all my attachments, e.g. Test Plans -> Runs the additional api calls to attachments are not made. Microsoft need to figure out why not.

Comment: You can try to test in a new project or organization to see if this problem can be reproduced. If it can be reproduced, I will help you create a new ticket in the developer forum and report the problem to the product group. :)

Comment: Can you please try repeating your example with a failed test that automatically attaches both a 'Standard_Console_Output.log' and a 'Standard_Error_Log' file. It is these tests that I'm struggling to see attachments for - 'attachments' api call is not made when browsing the test case. I'm having no problems seeing attachments added to passed tests that don't have these log attachments added by default by the test task. I believe it should work with or without these logging attachments, but if you know how to disable them let me know.

Comment: Just so you are aware I can replicate this in a completely different organization and project. I can also replicate with a different test runner. As mentioned above, create a failed test case that has a log attached - 'Standard_Console_Output.log' and/or 'Standard_Error_Log.log' (e.g. if using MsTest, add some Console.WriteLine statements to your failed test). Then browse that completed test case in azure devops. No 'attachments' api call is made, even though all the attachments are returned when calling the get test attachments api.

Comment: I tried with a failed test but these two log files are not automatically [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFMaj.png). You can check the task settings to see if the upload attachment is set

Comment: Your choice of test runner and why they aren't attached is for you to figure out. Your [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops) clearly states the following - 'If you use the Visual Studio Test task to run tests, diagnostic output logged from tests (using any of Console.WriteLine, Trace.WriteLine or TestContext.WriteLine methods), will appear as an attachment for a failed test.'

Comment: I see you are using JUnit. Please can you try replicating with MSTest, and adding 'Console.WriteLine' statements into your failed test. You can clone my example [here](https://github.com/Konnor5092/NewAttachmentsTest), or you can replicate the actual unit test file [here](https://github.com/Konnor5092/NewAttachmentsTest/blob/master/NUnitTestProject1/UnitTestProjectFramework/UnitTest1.cs). Add this to a build or release pipeline with the 'Visual Studio Test' task. 'Upload test attachments' makes no difference to this issue. Video replication [here](https://streamable.com/7k6m3)